# MongoError: Spring Boot throws E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have been trying to create a MongoDB application with Spring boot. But, before it starts it throws an exception of E11000 Dup. Key error in a collection. This error occurs at startup though I have verified all the points but, I didn't find any duplicate key in my data.
My data structure looks likes

```
@Document( collection = "IT" )
public class ItemType {
    @Id
    private String      id;
    private IV[] iv;
}

public class IV {
    private String        value;
    private AP[] aps;
}

@Document( collection = "AP" )
public class AP {
    @Id
    private String     id;
    @Indexed( unique = true )
    private String     apc;
    private String     dim;
    private string foc;
}
```

Whenever I start my spring boot application it throws following exception:

> E11000 duplicate key error collection: **p.IT** index: **iv.aps.apc** dup key:
>   { : "AVI" }

My dataset is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e846c5c3584fe7c7831283e"),
    "iv" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "M",
            "aps" : [ 
                {
                    "apc" : "MOV"
                }, 
                {
                    "apc" : "AVI"
                }
            ]
        }, 

        {
            "value" : "N",
            "aps" : [ 
                {
                    "apc" : "MOV"
                }, 
                {
                    "apc" : "AVI"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "O",
            "aps" : [ 
                {
                    "apc" : "MOV"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "P",
            "aps" : [ 
                {
                    "apc" : "MOV"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am new to MongoDB and it seems I am not making the data structure correctly. As I am willing to create reference to collection in a way that only few properties that I am using in another collection should be available there i.e. as you can see **AP** has more then 2 properties. But, I am using only **apc** which is needed by **IV**

Comment: Check if your `IT` collection has `apc_1` index. Try to drop it and start again

Comment: No IT doesn't have any index starts with apc only AP has one apc index which is understood.

Comment: Please post the result of `db.collection.getIndexes()` output from your collection.

Comment: You are probably trying to insert your data into a collection that already has some of the data. Either don't insert in this case or empty the collection prior to inserting.

Answer (score 1):

You have a unique index defined in class AP

```
    @Indexed( unique = true )
    private String     apc;
```

and then you have an array of AP object in class IV

```
private AP[] aps;
```

and an array of IV object in class IT

```
private IV[] iv;
```

The resulting index will enforce that no 2 documents can have `apc` fields with the same value.  An index in MongoDB is structured as a set of `k`->`v` pairs, where the `k` is the value indexed field, and `v` is the internal document identifier (not the _id).  If the same value appears multiple times in a single document, it will only be added to the index once.

The unique property is enforced at the index level, so a single document can have repeats of the value since it will only result in a single entry in the index, but no other document could then use that value because it would require adding a second copy of it in the index.

To bring this back around to your data, that sample document contains 2 different values for `iv.aps.apc`, `MOV`, and `AVI`.  Since that is indexed with the unique option, no other document in that collection can have either of those values in that field.